# Lens flare disapearing - three.js (LensFlare)

Tags: 3d, three.js

Here: https://jsfiddle.net/q703Lzsu/, with jpg image for flare and camera at `camera.position.z=80` or less everything works fine.

```
camera.position.z = 80;

new THREE.TextureLoader().load( 
    /*"https://ibin.co/3apA1ybsZXgx.png"*/
    "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/9/99/Map_of_the_full_sun.jpg", (texture3) => {

    console.log('hereAAA');
    var flareColor = new THREE.Color( 0xffffff );

    var lensFlare = new THREE.LensFlare( texture3, 200, 0.0, THREE.AddieAAA');
    var flareColor = new THREE.Color( 0xffffff );

    var lensFlare = new THREE.LensFlare( texture3, 200, 0.0, THREE.AdditiveBlending, flareColor );
    lensFlare.position.set( 0,0,10 );

    scene.add( lensFlare );
});
```

**But if I use `camera.position.z=110` or higher flare does not appear!**

If I use some number in between 80 and 110 (for example 100) flare gets invisible when looking towards it at small angles (camera `y-rotation` cca. `<-0.4, 0.4>`).

Answer (score 0):

Cameras in three.js have a near and far clipping frustum.

```
OrthographicCamera( left, right, top, bottom, near, far )

left — Camera frustum left plane.
right — Camera frustum right plane.
top — Camera frustum top plane.
bottom — Camera frustum bottom plane.
near — Camera frustum near plane.
far — Camera frustum far plane.
```

Try increasing the value of the last param.

Comment: In the fiddle I use perspective camera, with 1300 as far parameter, so it should suffice.

Answer (score 0):

That's just an eclipse :)
You don't see the lensflare when you put `camera.position.z=110` because it is hidden by the sun.
Comment the line which adds the sun mesh to the scene and you will understand better. The lensflare source point must not be positioned behind any object to be visible.

Comment: Lens flare is at z=10, and sun is at z=0 with radius of 5. So Lens flare is not eclipsed by the sun.

Comment: It is.... Did you comment the line to see what i mean ...? You must know that the origin of the lensflare is the center point of your texture, not the whole texture itself.

Comment: I know that if there is no sun behind, then there is no such behaviour. There is some kind of bug if there is an object behind the flare. I really don't understand how can sun eclipse flare if flare is in front of the sun by 5 units. If I move the camera to z=70 then there is no disappearing of flare.

Comment: You are right. The problem is coming from the way you have made your skybox. If i disable `scene.background = texture;` the lensflare is working well...  So maybe you could try to increase this scene box but i don't know if it is possible, else you could create a real skybox with a cube mesh.

Answer (score 0):

This was found to be a bug in three.js. It is solved in the current dev version of three.js library.